# Xcode broke switch case multiline indentation in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, indentation

In previous Xcode versions switch case multiline indentation was:

```
switch error {
    case .authError,
         .decodeError,
         .dataNotExists:
    return "Error"
}
```

but now it's **broken**:

```
switch error {
    case .authError,
           .decodeError,
           .dataNotExists:
    return "Error"
}
```

or

```
switch error {
    case
            .authError,
            .decodeError,
            .dataNotExists:
    return "Error"
}
```

[image: settings]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've made a feedback: `FB9974879 (Indentation wrong for multiline.)` in https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9974879

Comment: "Feedback not found". Meanwhile, Xcode 14 and even 14.2 were released, and the problem is still relevant.

Comment: You can't see other users feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you put all cases on new lines, including the first one, then it will get formatted in the way that you like, otherwise you could use AppCode and set a custom formatter or use a linter that would format switches using a set rule.

That is -

```
switch error {
case 
  .authError,
  .decodeError,
  .dataNotExists:
  return "Error"
}
```

Comment: Added edit in question. This way don't work too.

Comment: The cases get indented 1 tab away from the case keyword with this solution. Hopefully Apple fixes this soon